# What is a=b=c in python?

Tags: python, variables

I am quite confused, consecutive equal `=` can be used in python like:

```
a = b = c
```

What is this language feature called? Is there something I can read about that?

Can it be generated into 4 equals?

```
a = b = c = d
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is just a way to declare `a` and `b` as equal to `c`.

```
>>> c=2
>>> a=b=c
>>> a
2
>>> b
2
>>> c
2
```

So you can use as much as you want:

```
>>> i=7
>>> a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i
```

You can read more in [Multiple Assignment](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm) from this Python tutorial.

> Python allows you to assign a single value to several variables
>   simultaneously. For example:
>
> a = b = c = 1
>
> Here, an integer object is created with the value 1, and all three
>   variables are assigned to the same memory location. You can also
>   assign multiple objects to multiple variables. For example:
>
> a, b, c = 1, 2, "john"
>
> Here, two integer objects with values 1 and 2 are assigned to
>   variables a and b, and one string object with the value "john" is
>   assigned to the variable c.

---

There is also another fancy thing! You can swap values like this: `a,b=b,a`:

```
>>> a=2
>>> b=5
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> a
5
>>> b
2
```

Answer (score 3):

python support multi variable assignment at a time called multiassignment.

```
In [188]: a = b = c = d = 4

In [189]: a
Out[189]: 4

In [190]: b
Out[190]: 4

In [191]: c
Out[191]: 4

In [192]: d
Out[192]: 4

In [193]: a = 2

In [194]: b = 2
```

is same as for `immutable` object

```
In [195]: a, b = 2 #int is a immutable object like `tuple`, `str`
```

while this is not to be mean for mutable object like `list`, `dictionary`
read about [mutable and immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)